# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine':CordovaError: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview, info.plist

I'm getting some weird error while trying to add cordova wkwebview plugin in my existing application.

**Error: if i try to update ios cordova platform**

> /////////////////
>   admins-mbp:WKWebView admin$ cordova platform update ios
>   Updating ios project...
>   Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (updatePlatform is not callable from the iOS project API, you will need to do this manually.)
>   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Error: if i try to run cordova project from the CLI**

> //////////////////
>   admins-mbp:WKWebView admin$ cordova run
>   Error: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
>   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Error: if i try to add cordova plugin WKWebview**

> ///////////////
>   admins-mbp:WKWebView admin$ cordova platform update ios
>   Updating ios project...
>   Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (updatePlatform is not callable from the iOS project API, you will need to do this manually.)
>   admins-mbp:WKWebView admin$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
>   Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" via npm
>   Installing "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" for ios
>   Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine':CordovaError: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
>       at Object.parseProjectFile [as parse] (/Users/Tanuj/World Bank/CVS CodeBase/WKWebView/WKWebView/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/projectFile.js:50:15)
>       at Plugman.addPlugin (/Users/Tanuj/World Bank/CVS CodeBase/WKWebView/WKWebView/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/plugman/Plugman.js:69:31)
>       at Api.addPlugin (/Users/Tanuj/World Bank/CVS CodeBase/WKWebView/WKWebView/platforms/ios/cordova/Api.js:187:53)
>       at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:611:6)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:407:28
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
>       at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>   Error: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
>   admins-mbp:WKWebView admin$ 
>   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I'm new to this cordova platform, so i don't know what kind of error is this, also when i tried the same plugin in new project; it adds this plugin.

I think this is some cordova version issue. Please help me as i'm stuck with this and no way to move ahead.

Comment: I think we can solve this issue, if we can update cordova iOS platform. As i try same with new cordova project; and successfully added this plugin in newer project. We can do this by 1. Removing the current ios platform... which will also remove my project files.. which i don't want. 2. Updating the ios platfrom.. which is giving me unknown error.

Answer (score 2):

I have the similar error and found the solution [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/)

Basically, I've this issue on ionic. But doesn't matter you can use this solution.

1. `cordova platform remove ios`
2. `cordova platform list` for being sure, that ios platform deleted
3. `cordova platform add ios --save`

And it is.

If anyone have the same error on android, you can only replace the `ios` with `android`.

Hope it helps.